# TypeError: Module object is not callable

Tags: python

Simple problem, but I just figure out why is it happening.

```
>>>help(max)

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: 'module' object is not callable
```

Comment: sorry .. it's working now :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have imported a module named `help`.

There are two work-arounds:

1. Access the built-in function directly, bypassing the global module name:

   ```
   __builtins__.help(max)
   ```
2. Remove the `help` global by deleting it again:

   ```
   del help
   ```

Comment: Why do you feel the need to post this as an answer immediately after posting the same thing as a comment? Furthermore, on a question that fits the "cannot be reproduced" close reason? Why not comment, closevote and move on?

Comment: @l4mpi: because I can a) reproduce it, and b), I had an additional approach that made this worthy of a full-blown answer instead of just a comment.

Comment: @l4mpi: and the OP *solved* the problem; `del help` worked and things are working again now.

Comment: @l4mpi: last but not least, this is a puzzling problem for anyone who doesn't yet understand that `help()` is just another Python function provided by the `__builtins__` module, and the work-around is quite simple. It is a question that others *can* run into.

Comment: Yes, the question was in fact solved - by your comment. And I'd disagree on your opinion that this question could be helpful to others; other people having the exact same problem (which I'd guess is rare) probably don't properly search for it; OP evidently didn't google his error message either... Also, please use the comment editing function instead of posting three comments as a reply.

Comment: @l4mpi: so you find the work-around of reaching directly into `__builtins__` unhelpful? **At best** this question is a dupe. It doesn't fall under 'no longer reproducable or typo'.

Comment: No, I just think you could have posted this workaround of yours as a comment; as OP already indicated that his problem was solved after your first comment. But I think we disagree here on principle - I'd simply not answer (outside of a comment) obviously unresearched questions, at least not without commenting to OP how his question could be improved. Also, I didn't say the `__builtins__` use is generally unhelpful, I simply doubt that people having this problem would be able to ever find this question, unless somebody else searches SO, finds it and closes theirs as a duplicate of this one.

Comment: @l4mpi: Then I think your standards are far from pragmatic.